# Update a Nested Array in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

**Course Schema**

```
Course
  name: String,
  code: String,
  sections: [
    reference: Number,
    professor: String,
    students: [
      id: ObjectId
    ]
  ]
```

There are many courses, each with many sections, each with many students.

Assuming the user's input is an array of reference values that exist in the database, how can I find a section by reference and add the user's id to the students array?

This is what I currently have, but it's not working and I'm not getting any errors either:

```
Course.update(
        { sections: { $elemMatch: { reference: references[i] } } },
        { $addToSet: { students: userId } },
        { new: true, upsert: true },
        function (err, sectionAdded) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('saving references error');
                return res.status(500).send({ message: 'saving references error' });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$elemMatch` to find by an array of embedded documents:

```
Course.static({
  findOneBySectionReferences (references) {
    return this.findOne({
      sections : {
        $elemMatch : {
          reference : {$in : references}
        }
      }
    });
  }
})

function addUserId (userId, references) {
  return (
    Course.findOneBySectionReferences(references).exec()
          .then((course) => {
            course.sections.forEach((section) => {
              references.forEach((reference) => {
                if (section.reference === reference) {
                  section.students.push({id : userId});
                }
              });
            });
            return course.save();
          })
  );
}

addUserId(userId, references)
.then((updatedCourse) => {
  console.log('Updated');
});
```

Comment: I edited my answer with what I had initially. Thanks for your time.

Comment: For you updated code, you are adding `userId` to the array `students` which is not in your `Course` object. Also, for your `students` array, it should be an array of embedded documents which contain an `id` property, your code does not even match with the schema. Finally, I think `$addToSet` does not support nested array of embedded documents.

Comment: I see there is `references[i]`, I assume you are calling `.update()` in a loop, which is not recommended. Calling `.update()` multiple times for a single request could be expensive.